# Mule Sql Query - passing parameters to the IN operator

Tags: sql, mule

I'm trying to create a mule flow that does a lot of DB (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 DB) operations.

The first DB query I do returns a list of IDs

```
select id from first_table;
```

I run the payload through a Java transformer that builds an ArrayList:
[1,2,3,4,5]
and then save it as a variable **indices**

Then I try to use this Array in another query

```
select * from another_table where first_table_fk in (#[flowVars.indices]);
```

But no matter what I do I keep getting the error

The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.

Mule can't handle the java.util.ArrayList (or a regular array, int[]) when using the IN operator.

I then tried creating the whole query as a string variable (and then referencing it in the  ).

This results with an exception: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SQL Strategy found for SQL statement: #[flowVars.queryString]

Can you please help me with my problem (using the IN operator in Mule sql queries) ?

I am using Mule studio 3.4.0 CE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mule uses statements (from java.sql) and thus doesn't support using IN in that way. Every occurance of MEL-expression (#[]) will be replaced by a question mark (?) and the actual values will be passed as parameters. I suggest you solve this by building the query dynamically and assign it to the JDBC-connector, and the execute it using a generic endpoint.

1. Create a Java class like this:

   ```
   public class CustomQueryBuilder implements Callable {
       @Override
       public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
           JdbcConnector c = (JdbcConnector) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupConnector("JDBC_connector");

           StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
           String queryBase = "select * from another_table where first_table_fk in (";
           query.append(queryBase);

           int numIndices = ((ArrayList<Integer>)eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("indices")).size();
           ArrayList<String> indices = new ArrayList<String>();
           for(int i=0; i<numIndices; i++) {
                   indices.add("#[flowVars.indices[" + i + "]");
           }
           query.append(StringUtils.join(indices, ", "));
           query.append(")");

           String finalQuery = query.toString();

           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
           String queryDigest = String.format("%1$032X",new BigInteger(1, md.digest(finalQuery.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

           if (!c.getQueries().containsKey(queryDigest)) {
                   c.getQueries().put(queryDigest, finalQuery);
           }

           eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty("generatedQueryKey", queryDigest);

           return eventContext.getMessage();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use it in your flow after you set the "indices" flow var.

   ```
   <component class="CustomQueryBuilder"/>
   ```
3. Then insert an generic outbound endpoint instead of your jdbc outbound endpoint and reference the created query.

   ```
   <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="jdbc://#[flowVars.generatedQueryKey]" />
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I have discovered other Mule query weaknesses (as soon as the queries get a bit more complex with joins etc) the problems arise. By using a custom Java transformer I got a reference to the JdbcConnector as you've shown and then created a PreparedStatement from it. Not very elegant but it works and you can actually debug it.